# Variable scope in functions

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have a SCOPE problem. When I declare "var text" outside the function all works. But inside the function it works only in the first part. Here is what I mean:

This is a buffer function. Executing buffer("anything") saves "anything". Executing buffer() - without the properties will return all properties.

- buffer("Al")
- buffer("ex")
- buffer() <= should return Alex

But the SCOPE of "text" is wrong and it does not return the saved properties.

```js
  function makeBuffer() {
    var text = "";
    if (arguments.length != 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(`Adding argument - (${arguments[i]})`);
        text += arguments[i];
        console.log(`New text - (${text})`);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`text - (${text})`);
      return text;
    }
  }
  var buffer = makeBuffer;


  buffer("One", "Two");
  document.write(buffer());
```

Answer (score 5):

That is normal behaviour.

A variable defined in a given scope goes away when the scope goes away. Each call the to the function creates a new scope.

Declaring the variable outside the function is the standard way to share a value between invocations of it.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a factory:

```js
function makeBuffer() {
  var text = "";
  
  return function buffer() {
    if (arguments.length != 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(`Adding argument - (${arguments[i]})`);
        text += arguments[i];
        console.log(`New text - (${text})`);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`text - (${text})`);
      return text;
    }
  }
}

var buffer = makeBuffer();

buffer("One", "Two");
document.write(buffer());
```

Comment: no need to return named function : `return function buffer() `

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest — If you don't return it, how do you expect to call it?

Comment: @Quentin He just means there's no need to name the function. It could be `return function()`

Comment: @Quentin, the final function is `var buffer = makeBuffer();`. That is what you are calling

Comment: It's still best practise to name it. It makes it much easier to see what is going on when you look at a stacktrace in a debugger.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it's better to leave it named. It emphasizes that `makeBuffer` is a `buffer` factory, and also makes stack traces clearer because the name is there rather than just `[anonymous function]`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest — Calling `var buffer = makeBuffer();` assigns the function to `buffer` which you then call as a function `buffer("foo", "bar"); console.log(buffer());`. If you don't return the function declared inside `makeBuffer` then the value assigned to that variable is `undefined` which isn't a function so it would error.

Comment: @Quentin, your last comment is pretty obvious. I don't know why you've wrote it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, in case the OP doesn't need a factory - you're making no sense too

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest — Because you said there was no need to return the named function. If that advice was followed then it wouldn't work.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest — It isn't clear if the OP needs a factory or not. They didn't say why they wanted to declare `text` inside the function. It is possible their goal was to avoid making it a global. Using a factory would solve that problem.

Comment: @Quentin, *If that advice was followed then it wouldn't work* - Really? So this code `function makeBuffer() {
  var text = "";  
  return function () {
    console.log(arguments);
  }
}

var buffer = makeBuffer();
buffer("One", "Two");` would not work?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest — Your advice was to **not return** the named function. The code you just put matches with 4castle's interpretation of what you said, but you responded to my interpretation when I asked *If you don't return it, how do you expect to call it?*.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using an object. This will make your code much more organized.

```js
var Buffer = function() {
  this.text = "";
}
Buffer.prototype.append = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    this.text += arguments[i];
  }
}
Buffer.prototype.get = function() {
  return this.text;
}

var buffer = new Buffer();
buffer.append("One", "Two");
document.write(buffer.get());
```

Using ES6 the syntax gets even sweeter:

```js
class Buffer {
  constructor() {
    this.text = "";
  }
  append() {
    this.text = this.text.concat(...arguments);
  }
  get() {
    return this.text;
  }
}

var buffer = new Buffer();
buffer.append("One", "Two");
document.write(buffer.get());
```

Comment: I'm surprised that the `get` keyword in the ES6 implementation works as you expected. I would have guessed the interpreter would throw something like `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree. However it's only a keyword when used in conjunction with a function name.

Answer (score 1):

As Quentin properly pointed out in his answer, that is a normal behavior.

An alternative option to keep the value *on* your function without declaring the variable outside is scope is to add it as a property to the function itself.

As in JavaScript a function is a first class object, you can put such data directly into function object (like in any other objects).

An example below, please note how to get property `text` from your function (`buffer.text`).

```js
function makeBuffer() {
  makeBuffer.text = "";
  if (arguments.length != 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      console.log(`Adding argument - (${arguments[i]})`);
      makeBuffer.text += arguments[i];
      console.log(`New text - (${makeBuffer.text})`);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`text - (${makeBuffer.text})`);
    return makeBuffer.text;
  }
}

var buffer = makeBuffer;

buffer("Al", "ex");
console.log(`buffer.text - (${buffer.text})`);
```

Alternatively consider using a closure in order to keep the value of text between function calls.

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables
>   (variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope).
>   In other words, these functions 'remember' the environment in which
>   they were created. [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
let makeBuffer = function() {
  // closure
  let text = "";
  return function() {
    if (arguments.length != 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(`Adding argument - (${arguments[i]})`);
        text += arguments[i];
        console.log(`New text - (${text})`);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`text - (${text})`);
      return text;
    }
  }
};
var buffer = makeBuffer();
buffer("Al", "ex");
```